# Make new array from specifed string?

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have this kind of simple array:

```
$puctures=array('1_noname.jpg','2_new.jpg','1_ok.jpg','3_lets.jpg','1_stack.jpg','1_predlog.jpg','3_loli.jpg');
```

I want to make new array that i will only have elements thats starts with 1_ 
Example

```
$new=array('1_noname.jpg','1_ok.jpg','1_stack.jpg','1_predlog.jpg');
```

Something like array_pop but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple loop will do.

```
foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
    if (substr($picture, 0, 2) == "1_") {
        $new[] = $picture;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

See [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$new = array_filter(
    $puctures,
    function($a) {return substr($a, 0, 2) == '1_'; }
);
```

Comment: I knew I should have used `array_filter`. I just could couldn't think of it when answering.

Comment: +1 Probably the most straight forward & simplest answer of the bunch =)

Answer (score 3):

Use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to get your array:

```
$new = array_filter($puctures, function($item)
{
   //here strpos() may be a better option:
   return preg_match('/^1_/', $item);
});
```

Comment: `preg_match` is better. The compiled regex is cached. `strpos` walks through the whole `$item` before determining that the found position is != 0.

Answer (score 2):

This examples uses [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) & [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$FirstPictures = array();
foreach( $pictures as $pic => $value ) { 
   if ( strpos( $value, '1_' ) !== 0 ) {
      array_push( $FirstPictures, $pic );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$puctures=array('1_noname.jpg','2_new.jpg','1_ok.jpg','3_lets.jpg','1_stack.jpg','1_predlog.jpg','3_loli.jpg');
  $new=array();
  foreach($puctures as $value)
   {
   if(strchr($value,'1'))
   $new[]=$value;
   }
   echo "<pre>";  print_r($new);
```